# Null returned for lazy loading

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, lazy-loading

I have a test context set up like this:

```
class TestAppContext : ContextInterface
    {

        public DbSet<Person> Persons {get; set;}
        public DbSet<House> Houses { get; set; }

        public TestAppContext()
        {
            this.Persons = new TestPersonDbSet();
            this.Houses = new TestHousesDbSet();
        }

        public int SaveChanges(){
            return 0;
        }
        public void MarkAsModified(Object item) {

        }

        public void Dispose() { }

    }
```

The models look like this:

```
class Person{
    [Key]
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
}

class House{
    [Key]
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string address {get; set;}
    public int personId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("personId")]
    public virtual Person person {get; set;}
}
```

Now if I run this unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void GetServiceRequest_User()
        {
            TestAppContext context = new TestAppContext();
            House house = new House() {id=1, address="Middle of Nowhere", personId=3};
            Perosn person = new Person() {id=3, name="Some Dude"};
            context.Houses.Add(house);
            context.Persons.Add(person);

            HousesController controller = new HousesController(context);
            var resultRaw = controller.GetHouse(house.id);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(resultRaw, typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<House>));

            OkNegotiatedContentResult<House> result = resultRaw as OkNegotiatedContentResult<House>;
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.IsNotNull(result.Content.person);
            Assert.AreEqual(result.Content.person.id, result.Content.personId);
            Assert.AreEqual(result.Content.person.id, person.id);
        }
```

It fails, due to the fact that the result.Content.person is null. Why is this? The person, as I understand it, should lazily load since the ids match, but this seems not to be the case.

As Requested, the GetHouse method:

```
[Route("{id:int}", Name="DisplayHouse")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(House))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetHouse(int id)
        {
            House house = db.Houses.Find(id);
            if (house == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(house);
        }
```

Comment: show us HouseController

Comment: @RobertLevy added the get method above. The controller is a basic scaffolded controller.

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with lazy loading; right now, there isn't any `SaveChanges()` call, so a call to a class with a different context to retrieve what was added by the first context will never find anything, because nothing was actually added to the database.

Comment: honestly, this test doesn't really make much sense; and it's not really a Unit Test the way it's set up, it's an Integration Test.

Comment: @Claies I see what you're saying. I'm using mock objects to unit test my code functionality. What would you suggest in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this, being that you are setting the Id as Key i dont think you should be setting the values, adding the person to the house should wire up the relationship. Being that you are not saving context lazy loading does not apply. for that you would want to save the changes to the context.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetServiceRequest_User()
    {
        TestAppContext context = new TestAppContext();
        House house = new House() {address="Middle of Nowhere"};
        Perosn person = new Person() {name="Some Dude"};
        house.person = person;
        context.Houses.Add(house);


        HousesController controller = new HousesController(context);
        var resultRaw = controller.GetHouse(house.id);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(resultRaw, typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<House>));

        OkNegotiatedContentResult<House> result = resultRaw as OkNegotiatedContentResult<House>;
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result.Content.person);
        Assert.AreEqual(result.Content.person.id, result.Content.personId);
        Assert.AreEqual(result.Content.person.id, person.id);
    }
```